# Save content to a file in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to save a content like a string or an image to a file(like "C:\temp") in Chrome extension?
Does chrome or js provide any API to handle file system?

Comment: Do explicitly need to interact with the OS file system or do you just need a place to store your data like local storage?

Comment: I wanna interact with the OS file system, not chrome local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way for a chrome extension to manage the filesystem aside from using a custom [NPAPI plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) con can get more info about using NPAPI plugin at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html

Comment: yeah, i am using NPAPI to handle this now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to trigger a system file save dialogue via JS.

```
function exportToFile() {
    var myString = "Lorem ipsum.";

    window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(myString));
}
exportToFile();
```

Another way is to use the new FILE API.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: BTW, if you want to download a lot of existing files, you might want to just generate a set of URLs and use a download manager to save them.

Comment: There is also `chrome.downloads` API.